# How to create a list of word with specific length

Tags: c

Im currently writing a C programming to create a list of word with specific length.

For example, I have a string of ten letter

**ABCDEFGHIJ**

and wanted to create a list of word where the length is 2 that is

**AB,BC,CD,DE,EF,FG,GH,HI,IJ**.

For now I can only create

AB,CD,EF,GH,IJ

with my coding

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    /*q=length of query sequence, W=length of substring, t=(q-w)+1*/
    char array[5][3],length[3];
    int i=1;
    FILE *input;

    input=fopen("string.txt", "r");

    /*stores and prints the data from the string*/
        while(fgets(length,3,input))
        {
            strcpy(array[i],length);
            printf(">%d\n%s\n\n",i,array[i]);
            i++;
         }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I point the array to starts the next word at position from the second letter not the third letter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all you need to read the *whole* string into an array. Then it's easy to loop over that array and fetch the characters you want from it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Why doesn't it compile?

Comment: Your algorithm could look like this. `while (there are still letters) { print previous letter;  print current letter;  get next letter}`.  Adapt to C as needed. No need for arrays, much less 2D arrays.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It can compile. The ten letter string is in a text file. Please refer to line 10

Comment: @iBug It can compile. The ten letter string is in a text file. Please refer to line 10 in the coding.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Did you mistake it for `strncpy()`? That one does require 3 but `strcpy()` only requires 2.

Comment: @iBug right, I misinterpreted `length` as integer!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti This is a good example of how important variable naming is :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your question, you have tor ead your file char by char, not 2 char by 2 char :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[3] = "";
    FILE *input = NULL;

    if (!(input = fopen("string.txt", "r"))) {
        // Error
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (!fgets(str,3,input)) {
        // Error ?
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);

    for(int c = fgetc(input); c != EOF; c = fgetc(input)) {
        str[0] = str[1];
        str[1] = c;
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But a better way is to read the whole line (like with getline if you are on Linux) and simply display 2 char by 2 char ...

### ----------

---

Okay, so this is not really how SO work, but I'm gonna give you a piece of code.
But before that, some general advice :

Begin by testing your code with little data.
I mean, doing a test with an input of 10 char and a len of 2 is good, doing a test with an input of 3K+ char and a len of 100+ is insane. How do you expect to see if your code is good or bad ?

Cut your code in small function.
And do some "unitary" test on these function. That way, if something failed, you will be able to quickly found the bug without a debugger. If the function to retrieve data work but you end up with a wrong result, the maybe the problem lies when you construct your solution. If the result's construction work but you end up with bad value in your file, then maybe it's the writing function that is at fault. etc etc.

Use str* function.
Doing a manually shift to the left with a string of len 2 is ok, but doing it with a string of 115 is insane ! How many time did you spend on that ?

---

This is the piece of code that will take a string as an input an do what you want.
Since the array can have any length, the last value of the array is NULL.
It's like a string : to know the len, you search for the particuliar value '\0'. Here, it's not '\0' but rather NULL.

The result array and the string's result are good thanks to calloc that implictly set all array pointeur to NULL and all string content to \0.
That's why strncpy doesn't fail.

```
// TODO Do the description
char** Magic(const char * const input, size_t len)
{
    char   **array          = NULL;
    size_t arraySize        = 0;
    size_t inputLen         = strlen(input);
    char   **returnFunction = NULL;

    // Basic check (assert ?)
    if (!len) {
        // TODO Error message
        goto END_FUNCTION;
    }

    // Calcul of the array length
    if (len <= inputLen) {
        arraySize = inputLen - len + 1;
    }
    // Last array value must be NULL in order to know the array length
    ++arraySize;

    if (!(array = calloc(arraySize, sizeof(*array)))) {
        // TODO Error message
        goto END_FUNCTION;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; ++i) {
        if (!(array[i] = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(*array[i])))) {
            // TODO Error message
            goto END_FUNCTION;
        }
        strncpy(array[i], input + i, len);
    }

    returnFunction = array;
    array = NULL;

    /* GOTO */END_FUNCTION:
    if (array) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
            free(array[i]);
        }
        free(array);
    }
    return (returnFunction);
}



int main(void)
{
    char   *input   = "ABCDEFGIHJ";
    size_t inputLen = strlen(input);
    char   **result = NULL;

    for (size_t len = 1; len <= inputLen; ++len) {
        // Get result
        if (!(result = Magic(input, len))) {
            // TODO error log ?
            continue;
        }
        // Display result
        printf("result for %zu len : ", len);
        for (size_t i = 0; result[i]; ++i) {
            printf("%s%s", result[i], result[i + 1] ? ", " : "\n");
        }
        // Free result
        for (size_t i = 0; result[i]; ++i) {
            free(result[i]);
        }
        free(result);
        result = NULL;
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What's left up to you is : retrieving the data (and then use it in the "input" argument) and display/writing the data.
For both of these, **DO A FUNCTION**.

And test. lot of test.
Do not forget to check if there is a failure when calling a function.

Comment: Why do you feel a need to make `return` look like a function? It's kind of the opposite ...

Comment: @unwind are you referring to the fact that I use unecessary parenthesis when I do a return ? It's just a convention used when I was in school that didn't really shock me, and it was used too on my first work (guess the previous dev come from the same scholl as me), so I keep using it. No really point doing so thougth (and it's not like I want my return to look like a function).

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. I think I also did this many years ago, and it's interesting to see that it still pops up. I have a fascination for "style guidelines" that in my opinion make the code harder to both write and read, somewhere someone must have seen some kind of benefit but it's hard to understand what it was.

Comment: @unwind The benefit is simply to have all people working with the same guideline understand more simply eahc other. In the case of surparenthesis return, I bet that it was designed for beginner : It seem more reassuring to have all your return "contained".

Comment: @Tom's There error during compiling return(EXIT_FAILURE) and return(EXIT_SUCCESS), so I change to something else. also I change the variable naming from str to wmers. no error during compiling but no output. Cant the for loop is in the while block?

Comment: @dayanasaiful EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS are defined in stdlib.h that I have included, but not you on your first code. The for loop should not block. On which OS do you work ?

Comment: @Tom's Ive included stdlib.h but no output. Maybe the for loop cant be written in while block. OS = Windows 10

Comment: @dayanasaiful That code work well for me ... Create a new projet, and put only the code that I provided you into it.

Comment: @dayanasaiful Yes, and your code is nothing close from mine. First step, display the desired result. That's what my code is doing, and is doing ok. Second, add code to retain in memory the desired result. My code doesn't do that, and you wrongly trying to do that. Moreover, if you have more than 10 letter in your incoming file, your code will be broken. If the length of your word change, idem, your code is broken. It's not really more difficult to have a general solution for your specific problem. But take down your probleme step by step.

Comment: @Tom's Ive tried your code, its working, but its hard for me to understand. What does this '''' used for? why dont you use else? Why declare c as interger in for loop? Ive edit the code a little `printf(">%d\n%s\n\n",i,wmers); i++;` but the out starts >1 BC, why?

Comment: @dayanasaiful Then it's better to ask question about the code that you doesn't understand rather than trying thing that you clearly don't understand. The `char str[3] = "";` is just initializing str to an empty string (str[0] will be equal to \0). On this code, it doesn't really matter whether or not str is initlialized, but it's an habit of mine. Why I don't use else ... where ? on the first if, it's because there is a return (so the else is implicit), on the second it's because I don't know what you want to do in this case, so it's up to you to do something.

Comment: @Tom's Ive set the wmers to 115 and the total character in the text file 3426 with 4 types of character A,G,T,C. But I can only view half of the substring . So I intended to view it in a text file. Ive edited the code. Please refer to the new posted code. The string printed in the command prompt is not the same as in the text file. Do you know why?

Comment: @dayanasaiful you're insane ... I've edited my first answer. Take a look and try to understand as much as you can. Are you familiar with memory allocation ?

Comment: @dayanasaiful Are you sequencing DNAs? A little context or an hint of what you are actually trying to accomplish may be useful.

Comment: @Tom's Im not familiar with memory allocation, but ill try my best to search about it. So you suggest that I do a display and writing using a function?

Comment: @Bob__ You familiar with DNA sequencing? I am aiming to cut the 3426 sequence to 114 length of subsequence to find region of interest. Before this I just copy and paste.

Comment: @dayanasaiful Yes. Imagine if you have a function that magically give you a line from a file (or all the file), then you could just call this function and have the wanted string. From your question and your code, it seem to me that you want to chew more than you could. Not knowing memory allocation while wanting different result len / input len will be troublesome. If you want to skip memory allocation, it's best to determine the maximum result len / input len and have static array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char wmers[115];
int i = 1, j = 2;

FILE *input = NULL;
FILE *output;

if (!(input = fopen("exon11.txt", "r"))) {
    // Error
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (!fgets(wmers,115,input)) {
    // Error ?
}
printf(">%d\n%s\n\n",i,wmers);
i++;
output=fopen("2.txt", "w");
fputs(wmers,output);
for(int c = fgetc(input); c != EOF; c = fgetc(input))
    {
        wmers[0] = wmers[1];
        wmers[1] = wmers[2];
        wmers[2] = wmers[3];
        wmers[3] = wmers[4];
        wmers[4] = wmers[5];
        wmers[5] = wmers[6];
        wmers[6] = wmers[7];
        wmers[7] = wmers[8];
        wmers[8] = wmers[9];
        wmers[9] = wmers[10];
        wmers[10] = wmers[11];
        wmers[11] = wmers[12];
        wmers[12] = wmers[13];
        wmers[13] = wmers[14];
        wmers[14] = wmers[15];
        wmers[15] = wmers[16];
        wmers[16] = wmers[17];
        wmers[17] = wmers[18];
        wmers[18] = wmers[19];
        wmers[19] = wmers[20];
        wmers[20] = wmers[21];
        wmers[21] = wmers[22];
        wmers[22] = wmers[23];
        wmers[23] = wmers[24];
        wmers[24] = wmers[25];
        wmers[25] = wmers[26];
        wmers[26] = wmers[27];
        wmers[27] = wmers[28];
        wmers[28] = wmers[29];
        wmers[29] = wmers[30];
        wmers[30] = wmers[31];
        wmers[31] = wmers[32];
        wmers[32] = wmers[33];
        wmers[33] = wmers[34];
        wmers[34] = wmers[35];
        wmers[35] = wmers[36];
        wmers[36] = wmers[37];
        wmers[37] = wmers[38];
        wmers[38] = wmers[39];
        wmers[39] = wmers[40];
        wmers[40] = wmers[41];
        wmers[41] = wmers[42];
        wmers[42] = wmers[43];
        wmers[43] = wmers[44];
        wmers[44] = wmers[45];
        wmers[45] = wmers[46];
        wmers[46] = wmers[47];
        wmers[47] = wmers[48];
        wmers[48] = wmers[49];
        wmers[49] = wmers[50];
        wmers[50] = wmers[51];
        wmers[51] = wmers[52];
        wmers[52] = wmers[53];
        wmers[53] = wmers[54];
        wmers[54] = wmers[55];
        wmers[55] = wmers[56];
        wmers[56] = wmers[57];
        wmers[57] = wmers[58];
        wmers[58] = wmers[59];
        wmers[59] = wmers[60];
        wmers[60] = wmers[61];
        wmers[61] = wmers[62];
        wmers[62] = wmers[63];
        wmers[63] = wmers[64];
        wmers[64] = wmers[65];
        wmers[65] = wmers[66];
        wmers[66] = wmers[67];
        wmers[67] = wmers[68];
        wmers[68] = wmers[69];
        wmers[69] = wmers[70];
        wmers[70] = wmers[71];
        wmers[71] = wmers[72];
        wmers[72] = wmers[73];
        wmers[73] = wmers[74];
        wmers[74] = wmers[75];
        wmers[75] = wmers[76];
        wmers[76] = wmers[77];
        wmers[77] = wmers[78];
        wmers[78] = wmers[79];
        wmers[79] = wmers[80];
        wmers[80] = wmers[81];
        wmers[81] = wmers[82];
        wmers[82] = wmers[83];
        wmers[83] = wmers[84];
        wmers[84] = wmers[84];
        wmers[85] = wmers[86];
        wmers[86] = wmers[87];
        wmers[87] = wmers[88];
        wmers[88] = wmers[89];
        wmers[89] = wmers[90];
        wmers[90] = wmers[91];
        wmers[91] = wmers[92];
        wmers[92] = wmers[93];
        wmers[93] = wmers[94];
        wmers[94] = wmers[95];
        wmers[95] = wmers[96];
        wmers[96] = wmers[97];
        wmers[97] = wmers[98];
        wmers[98] = wmers[99];
        wmers[99] = wmers[100];
        wmers[100] = wmers[101];
        wmers[101] = wmers[102];
        wmers[102] = wmers[103];
        wmers[103] = wmers[104];
        wmers[104] = wmers[105];
        wmers[105] = wmers[106];
        wmers[106] = wmers[107];
        wmers[107] = wmers[108];
        wmers[108] = wmers[109];
        wmers[109] = wmers[110];
        wmers[110] = wmers[111];
        wmers[111] = wmers[112];
        wmers[112] = wmers[113];
        wmers[113] = wmers[114];
        wmers[114] = c;

    printf(">%d\n%s\n\n",j,wmers);
    j++;

    fputs(wmers,output);
    }

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

this is the content of exon11.txt.

> CTGCTTGTGAATTTTCTGAGACGGATGTAACAAATACTGAACATCATCAACCCAGTAATAATGATTTGAACACCACTGAGAAGCGTGCAGCTGAGAGGCATCCAGAAAAGTATCAGGGTAGTTCTGTTTCAAACTTGCATGTGGAGCCATGTGGCACAAATACTCATGCCAGCTCATTACAGCATGAGAACAGCAGTTTATTACTCACTAAAGACAGAATGAATGTAGAAAAGGCTGAATTCTGTAATAAAAGCAAACAGCCTGGCTTAGCAAGGAGCCAACATAACAGATGGGCTGGAAGTAAGGAAACATGTAATGATAGGCGGACTCCCAGCACAGAAAAAAAGGTAGATCTGAATGCTGATCCCCTGTGTGAGAGAAAAGAATGGAATAAGCAGAAACTGCCATGCTCAGAGAATCCTAGAGATACTGAAGATGTTCCTTGGATAACACTAAATAGCAGCATTCAGAAAGTTAATGAGTGGTTTTCCAGAAGTGATGAACTGTTAGGTTCTGATGACTCACATGATGGGGAGTCTGAATCAAATGCCAAAGTAGCTGATGTATTGGACGTTCTAAATGAGGTAGATGAATATTCTGGTTCTTCAGAGAAAATAGACTTACTGGCCAGTGATCCTCATGAGGCTTTAATATGTAAAAGTGAAAGAGTTCACTCCAAATCAGTAGAGAGTAATATTGAAGACAAAATATTTGGGAAAACCTATCGGAAGAAGGCAAGCCTCCCCAACTTAAGCCATGTAACTGAAAATCTAATTATAGGAGCATTTGTTACTGAGCCACAGATAATACAAGAGCGTCCCCTCACAAATAAATTAAAGCGTAAAAGGAGACCTACATCAGGCCTTCATCCTGAGGATTTTATCAAGAAAGCAGATTTGGCAGTTCAAAAGACTCCTGAAATGATAAATCAGGGAACTAACCAAACGGAGCAGAATGGTCAAGTGATGAATATTACTAATAGTGGTCATGAGAATAAAACAAAAGGTGATTCTATTCAGAATGAGAAAAATCCTAACCCAATAGAATCACTCGAAAAAGAATCTGCTTTCAAAACGAAAGCTGAACCTATAAGCAGCAGTATAAGCAATATGGAACTCGAATTAAATATCCACAATTCAAAAGCACCTAAAAAGAATAGGCTGAGGAGGAAGTCTTCTACCAGGCATATTCATGCGCTTGAACTAGTAGTCAGTAGAAATCTAAGCCCACCTAATTGTACTGAATTGCAAATTGATAGTTGTTCTAGCAGTGAAGAGATAAAGAAAAAAAAGTACAACCAAATGCCAGTCAGGCACAGCAGAAACCTACAACTCATGGAAGGTAAAGAACCTGCAACTGGAGCCAAGAAGAGTAACAAGCCAAATGAACAGACAAGTAAAAGACATGACAGCGATACTTTCCCAGAGCTGAAGTTAACAAATGCACCTGGTTCTTTTACTAAGTGTTCAAATACCAGTGAACTTAAAGAATTTGTCAATCCTAGCCTTCCAAGAGAAGAAAAAGAAGAGAAACTAGAAACAGTTAAAGTGTCTAATAATGCTGAAGACCCCAAAGATCTCATGTTAAGTGGAGAAAGGGTTTTGCAAACTGAAAGATCTGTAGAGAGTAGCAGTATTTCATTGGTACCTGGTACTGATTATGGCACTCAGGAAAGTATCTCGTTACTGGAAGTTAGCACTCTAGGGAAGGCAAAAACAGAACCAAATAAATGTGTGAGTCAGTGTGCAGCATTTGAAAACCCCAAGGGACTAATTCATGGTTGTTCCAAAGATAATAGAAATGACACAGAAGGCTTTAAGTATCCATTGGGACATGAAGTTAACCACAGTCGGGAAACAAGCATAGAAATGGAAGAAAGTGAACTTGATGCTCAGTATTTGCAGAATACATTCAAGGTTTCAAAGCGCCAGTCATTTGCTCCGTTTTCAAATCCAGGAAATGCAGAAGAGGAATGTGCAACATTCTCTGCCCACTCTGGGTCCTTAAAGAAACAAAGTCCAAAAGTCACTTTTGAATGTGAACAAAAGGAAGAAAATCAAGGAAAGAATGAGTCTAATATCAAGCCTGTACAGACAGTTAATATCACTGCAGGCTTTCCTGTGGTTGGTCAGAAAGATAAGCCAGTTGATAATGCCAAATGTAGTATCAAAGGAGGCTCTAGGTTTTGTCTATCATCTCAGTTCAGAGGCAACGAAACTGGACTCATTACTCCAAATAAACATGGACTTTTACAAAACCCATATCGTATACCACCACTTTTTCCCATCAAGTCATTTGTTAAAACTAAATGTAAGAAAAATCTGCTAGAGGAAAACTTTGAGGAACATTCAATGTCACCTGAAAGAGAAATGGGAAATGAGAACATTCCAAGTACAGTGAGCACAATTAGCCGTAATAACATTAGAGAAAATGTTTTTAAAGAAGCCAGCTCAAGCAATATTAATGAAGTAGGTTCCAGTACTAATGAAGTGGGCTCCAGTATTAATGAAATAGGTTCCAGTGATGAAAACATTCAAGCAGAACTAGGTAGAAACAGAGGGCCAAAATTGAATGCTATGCTTAGATTAGGGGTTTTGCAACCTGAGGTCTATAAACAAAGTCTTCCTGGAAGTAATTGTAAGCATCCTGAAATAAAAAAGCAAGAATATGAAGAAGTAGTTCAGACTGTTAATACAGATTTCTCTCCATATCTGATTTCAGATAACTTAGAACAGCCTATGGGAAGTAGTCATGCATCTCAGGTTTGTTCTGAGACACCTGATGACCTGTTAGATGATGGTGAAATAAAGGAAGATACTAGTTTTGCTGAAAATGACATTAAGGAAAGTTCTGCTGTTTTTAGCAAAAGCGTCCAGAAAGGAGAGCTTAGCAGGAGTCCTAGCCCTTTCACCCATACACATTTGGCTCAGGGTTACCGAAGAGGGGCCAAGAAATTAGAGTCCTCAGAAGAGAACTTATCTAGTGAGGATGAAGAGCTTCCCTGCTTCCAACACTTGTTATTTGGTAAAGTAAACAATATACCTTCTCAGTCTACTAGGCATAGCACCGTTGCTACCGAGTGTCTGTCTAAGAACACAGAGGAGAATTTATTATCATTGAAGAATAGCTTAAATGACTGCAGTAACCAGGTAATATTGGCAAAGGCATCTCAGGAACATCACCTTAGTGAGGAAACAAAATGTTCTGCTAGCTTGTTTTCTTCACAGTGCAGTGAATTGGAAGACTTGACTGCAAATACAAACACCCAGGATCCTTTCTTGATTGGTTCTTCCAAACAAATGAGGCATCAGTCTGAAAGCCAGGGAGTTGGTCTGAGTGACAAGGAATTGGTTTCAGATGATGAAGAAAGAGGAACGGGCTTGGAAGAAAATAATCAAGAAGAGCAAAGCATGGATTCAAACTTAG

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer ?

Comment: @Bob__ yes that the one